# Why end-of-file indicator isn't working in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am practicing a programming task given in my course literature. The program will keep asking the user to enter student's grades until they enter end-of-file indicator.
What is happening in my case is typing ctrl+Z (on windows, as it instructs me in book) doesn't work. It happens nothing afetr I doing this. Is it a problem with my console window or program?

GradeBook class:

```
package gradebook;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeBook {

    private String courseName;
    private int totalGrade;
    private int gradeCounter;
    private int aCount;
    private int bCount;
    private int cCount;
    private int dCount;
    private int fCount;

//Create a contructor
    public GradeBook(String name) {
        courseName = name;
    }

    GradeBook() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public void setCourseName(String name) {
        courseName = name;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void displayMessage() {
        System.out.printf("Welcome to the course\n%s!\n\n", getCourseName());
    }

    public void inputGrade() {
        //int gradeEnteredByuser;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int gradeEnteredByuser;
        System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n %s\n %s\n", "Enter the integer grade in the range 0-100", "Type the end-of file indicator to terminate input:",
                "On Unix/Linux/Mac OS X type <Ctrl> d then press enter", "On windows type <Ctrl> z then press enter:");

        while (input.hasNext()) {

            //int gradeEnteredByuser;
            gradeEnteredByuser = input.nextInt();
            totalGrade += gradeEnteredByuser;
            gradeCounter++;
            incrementLetterGradeCounter(gradeEnteredByuser);

        }

    }

    private void incrementLetterGradeCounter(int gradeEnteredByuser) {

        switch (gradeEnteredByuser / 10) 
        {
            case 9:
            case 10:
                ++aCount;
                break;
            case 8:
                ++bCount;
                break;
            case 7:
                ++cCount;
                break;
            case 6:
                ++dCount;
            default:
                ++fCount;

        }

    }
    public void displayGradeReport(){
        System.out.println("\nGrade report");
        if(gradeCounter!=0){
            double average=(double)totalGrade/gradeCounter;
            System.out.printf("Total of the %d grades entered is %d\n", gradeCounter,totalGrade);
            System.out.printf("Class avereage is %.2f\n", average);
            System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", 
                    "Number of students who received each grade:",
                    "A: ", aCount,
                    "B: ", bCount,
                    "C: ", cCount,
                    "D: ", dCount,
                    "F: ", fCount);

        }else{
            System.out.println("No grade were entered:re");
        }
    }

}
```

GradeBookTest class:

```
package gradebook;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeBookTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GradeBook gb=new GradeBook("Introduction to computer science");
        gb.displayMessage();
        gb.inputGrade();
        gb.displayGradeReport();
        // TODO code application logic here
    }


}
```

Comment: In the `printf` use `%n` instead of `\n`. The will flush and on Windows output "\r\n" (the Windows line terminator).

Comment: Joop Eggen, what is the purpose of doing so? it doesn't affest on anything.

Comment: Just a comment; `%n` is the officially preferred way of denoting a line-end.